# Google Pub/Sub notification message voidedPurchaseNotification?

Tags: publish-subscribe

I scraped and parsed the notification message and found this data attribute.

1. Google Pub/Sub notification message voidedPurchaseNotification attribute only appears when refunding?
2. If not, please list the scenarios in which this attribute also exists.